# Adding a volume in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, window, volume, docker-volume

I am trying to create an image of Windows with additional things. My question is whether it is possible to include a specific volume when creating the container. For example, I would like to do:

`docker run --name container -v shared:c:\shared -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2-amd64 powershell`

There I am accessing the shared volume, but I want to do this in the dockerfile as a command.

I want something like this after running the container:

[image]

Thank you for the help

I tried to use the VOLUME command but I don't know if I am doing it right or it's not for what I am trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using VOLUME in dockerfile does not mount the volume during build, this only specifies a target where a directory can be mounted during container runtime (anonymous volume).

Because image build and container run can happen on different machines, so having VOLUME source defined in dockerfile (buid time) does not make sense.

Comment: Ok, I want to mount the Volume cause I want to add to the imagen a run for a .exe, and the .exe is in the Volume, so how can I do something like that? I am looking in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ and trying, but for now nothing worked (Or I don't know what I am doing).

Comment: you can `ADD / COPY` the .exe to the image, before the RUN and then (if it is not needed to be in the final image) you can remove the .exe with `RUN rm .exe`. 

Or you can use `RUN --mount=type=bind` [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run---mounttypebind)

Comment: I have tried that, but I have to access the volume anyway to transfer files, it would have been better if I could do it directly. I will do it with "copy" then and adding the volume with docker run, thank you.